# Syntax question regarding typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I'm learning React and Typescript and I have a question regarding the meaning of syntax.

Suppose I have a code snippet of test.tsx below.

```
// prop is defined somewhere over here.
...

private displayMyList = (props: Props) => {
   return <MyList name_prop={this.props.name} {...props}> </MyList>;
};
```

`<MyList name_prop={this.props.name}` means passing `this.props.name` value to `name_prop` of MyList component
so that MyList component can use `this.props.name` via `name_prop`

But what does `{...props}` inside of right-angle bracket `>` do?

If it's outside of right-angle bracket like

```
return <MyList name_prop={this.props.name}> {...props} </MyList>;
```

then it simply displays `{...props}`.

However, if `{...props}` is inside of `>`,

```
return <MyList name_prop={this.props.name} {...props}> </MyList>;
```

the
what does this syntax mean?

Answer (score 1):

it means "the other/rest" of props. Instead of naming each of your props, you can just propagate them down and then you can extract what you need.
Take a look: [Forwarding props](https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#forwarding-props-with-the-jsx-spread-syntax). With your example you can use: `<MyList {...props}> </MyList>` and then: `const MyList = ({name_prop}) => {}`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
const props = { a: 123 }
<Foo {...props} />
```

Is equivalent to:

```
<Foo a={123} />
```

So it applies an object as if the properties of that object were used as component props.

It this case, it's used as a way to forward props to an inner component.

So instead of:

```
function FooWrapper({ a, b }: Props) {
  return <Foo a={a} b={b} />
}
```

You can do:

```
function FooWrapper(props: Props) {
  return <Foo {...props} />
}
```

And you don't have to retype the prop names over again.